# Core Data one-to-many inverse relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, one-to-many

I'm making task manager app, I have two entities - Task and TaskCategory, every task has one category, while one category can have multiple tasks.

Classes looks like this:

TaskCategory.h:

```
@class Task;

@interface TaskCategory : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id color;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *task;
@end

@interface TaskCategory (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addTaskObject:(Task *)value;
- (void)removeTaskObject:(Task *)value;
- (void)addTask:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeTask:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Task.h:

```
@class TaskCategory;

@interface Task : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dueDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * done;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TaskCategory *category;

@end
```

When displaying list of tasks in table view, how can I access category of each task to get it's color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
task.category.color
```

This should work.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I've actually tried that but it didn't work because I made mistake somewhere else... now it works, thanks